# Появляется мгновенный скролл после переключения между вкладками

Tags: html, reactjs, прокрутка, next

Добавил в шапку страницы навигацию по этой странице, по id на соответствующих блоках. В стилях прописано `scroll-behavior: smooth`
По умолчанию всё работает правильно, но если перейти на какую-нибудь другую вкладку и вернуться, то вместо скролла мгновенное перемещение.
Добавил для проверки

```
useEffect(() => {
Console.time("рендер") 
Return () => console.timeEnd("рендер")
})
```

Согласно ему, при первой загрузке страница уходит 2-4мс, а после перемещения между вкладками от тысячи до десятков тысяч мс. Почему такое может происходить?

Comment: useEffect без зависимостей срабатывет ПОСЛЕ первого рендера страницы.

Comment: @SwaD За счёт того, что я не указал зависимости он срабатывает при каждой попытке переместиться навигацией по странице, причём не важно, на тот блок куда я воткнул этот useEffect или любой другой.
Однако периодически наблюдаю, что даже после переключения между вкладками скролл происходит нормально, плавно, и когда он плавный, в консоль ничего не пишется, то есть useEffect не срабатывает. Когда мгновенный - пишется, то есть useEffect срабатывает. Не понимаю что происходит